# Using Stokes' theorem show that $\int_{\partial S} \vec w \cdot d \vec r=0$.

Tags: calculus

Let $S$ be the surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ that lies above the plane $z=1$.
Let $\vec w(\vec r)$ be a vector field of the form $\vec w(\vec r)=f(\vec r)\vec r$, where $f(\vec r)$ is a continuously differentiable scalar field on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to show, using Stokes' theorem that $\int_{\partial S} \vec w \cdot d \vec r=0$.

I know that Stokes' theorem says that $\int_{S} (\nabla \times \vec w) \cdot d\vec S = \int_{\partial S} \vec w \cdot d \vec r$. I'm not sure how to make any progress from here though.

Comment: Looks like the statement you want to prove is not true.

Comment: What is $S$?  Or are you hoping this is true for absolutely every surface?

Comment: @NickPeterson I've edited my question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already pointed out that 
$$
\int_{\partial S}\vec{w}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_S(\nabla \times\vec{w})\cdot d\vec{S}.
$$
Now, let's unpack that curl computation a bit:
$$
\nabla\times\vec{w}=\nabla\times(f(\vec{r})\vec{r})=\nabla f(\vec{r})\times\vec{r}+f(\vec{r})(\nabla\times\vec{r})
$$
Now, the curl of $\vec{r}$ is $\vec{0}$; so, this simplifies to
$$
\nabla\times\vec{w}=\nabla f(\vec{r})\times\vec{r}.
$$
Now, consider the surface in question.  The normal to this surface at a given point $\vec{r}$ is just $\frac{\vec{r}}{\lvert\vec{r}\rvert}$. How does this direction relate to the direction of $\nabla\times\vec{w}$?

Comment: Are they parallel?

Comment: No -- they are orthogonal.  We showed that $\nabla\times\vec{w}$ is the same as $\nabla f(\vec{r})\times\vec{r}$... and remember, $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ is orthogonal to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

So, you now have that $\nabla\times\vec{w}$ is orthogonal to the normal to the surface -- in other words, all of its motion is ALONG the surface.  What does that tell you about this integral?

Comment: So since $\nabla \times \vec w$ is perpendicular to the normal the integral must be zero?

Comment: Yep! Flux is zero, since the field runs along the surface.